# How to execute a spark transformation eagerly?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, lazy-evaluation, scala-collections

As the transformations in spark are lazily evaluated, is there any way we can execute the transformation eagerly?

Is there any configuration change required to do that?

For example, I have the following scala code sample:

```
val args = Array("/Users/kvkv/Documents/backups/h/FeedsData.txt",
                "/Users/kvkv/Documents/backups/h/spark/output/FeedsDataOutput")
val conf = new SparkConf();
val sc = new SparkContext("local", "FeedsData.txt", conf);
val input= sc.textFile(args(0));
val feedsRdd = input.filter(line => line.contains("Feeds Info : "))
val feedswords = feedsRdd.flatMap(line => line.split(" "));
val counts = feedswords.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey{case (x, y) => x+y}
counts.saveAsTextFile(args(1))
```

As per normal executions, all transformations will be executed once an action is called.

Can any of these transformation be executed prior to action?

Answer (score 1):

I would say no. If any of the api is eagerly executed then it can be called as action rather than transformation. Reducebykey is a transformation but reduce is an action.
I am not mentioning what is the reason for lazy evaluation as you might have already aware of this.